# Special minimum spanning tree

Tags: c++14

There is a node that can only get one line, I use both kruskal and prim, but the judger said TLE(Time Limit Exceed).
Then I will describe the question. There are many computers, we need to connect all of them, we give the cost of connection between different computers, also we give the special number of computer which can be only connected by one line. Finally, we guarantee there is a answer and there is no Self-Loop, but there may have multiple edge which have different weight between same node.
Here is my kruskal code, it's TLE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct edge{
    int start;
    int end;
    int weight;
}Edge;

int special = 0;
int edgenum;
Edge _edge[600005];
int i, j, k;
int counter = 0;

bool Cmp(const edge &a, const edge &b){
    return a.weight < b.weight;
}

int getEnd(int vends[], int i){
    while(vends[i] != 0)
        i = vends[i];
    return i;
}

void kruskal(){
    int p1, p2, m, n, ans = 0;
    int vends[10005] = {0};
    sort(_edge, _edge+counter, Cmp);
    for(i = 0; i < edgenum; ++i){
        p1 = _edge[i].start;
        p2 = _edge[i].end;
        if ((p1 == k || p2 == k) && special)
            continue;

        m = getEnd(vends, p1);
        n = getEnd(vends, p2);

        if(m != n){
            if (p1 == k || p2 == k)
                special = 1;
            vends[m] = n;
            ans += _edge[i].weight;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    edgenum = m;
    while(m--){
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        _edge[counter].start = a;   //Get the Edge
        _edge[counter].weight = c;
        _edge[counter++].end = b;
//        _edge[counter].start = b;
//        _edge[counter].weight = c;
//        _edge[counter++].end = a;
    }
    kruskal();
}
```

Here is my Prim, but also TLE:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef char VertexType;

typedef struct node{
    int adjvex = 0;
    int weight = INT32_MAX;
    struct node *next = NULL;
}Node;

typedef struct vnode{
    VertexType data;
    Node *firstnode = NULL;
}Vnode;

Vnode node[10005];
int VNUM;
int n, m, k;
int lowcost[10005] = {0};
int addvnew[10005];  //未加入最小生成树表示为-1，加入则为0
int adjecent[10005] = {0};
bool is_special = false;
int flag;

void prim(int start){
    long long sumweight = 0;
    int i, j;
    Node *p = node[start].firstnode;

    for (i = 1; i <= VNUM; ++i) {   //重置
        addvnew[i] = -1;
    }

    while (p->next != NULL){
        if (lowcost[p->adjvex] == 0 || p->weight < lowcost[p->adjvex])
            lowcost[p->adjvex] = p->weight;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (lowcost[p->adjvex] == 0 || p->weight < lowcost[p->adjvex])
        lowcost[p->adjvex] = p->weight;

    addvnew[start] = 0;
//    adjecent[start] = start;
    if (start == k) {
        is_special = true;
        flag = 1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < VNUM; ++i) {
        int min = INT32_MAX;
        int v=-1;
        for (j = 1; j <= VNUM; ++j) {   //Find the min
            if (addvnew[j] == -1 && lowcost[j] < min && lowcost[j] != 0){
                min = lowcost[j];
                v = j;
            }
        }
        if (v != -1){   //if min is found
            if (flag == 1){
                for (int l = 0; l < 10005; ++l) {
                    lowcost[l] = 0;
                }
                flag = 0;
            }

            addvnew[v] = 0;

            sumweight += min;

            p = node[v].firstnode;
            while(p->next != NULL){
                if (is_special && p->adjvex == k){  //If find the special node
                    p = p->next;
                    continue;
                }
                if(addvnew[p->adjvex] == -1 && (lowcost[p->adjvex] == 0 || p->weight < lowcost[p->adjvex])){    //如果该点未连接
                    lowcost[p->adjvex] = p->weight;
                }
                p = p->next;
            }
            if (!(is_special && p->adjvex == k))
                if(addvnew[p->adjvex] == -1 && (lowcost[p->adjvex] == 0 || p->weight < lowcost[p->adjvex])){
                    lowcost[p->adjvex] = p->weight;
                }
        }
    }
    cout << sumweight << endl;
}

int main(){
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    VNUM = n;
    while (m--){
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        p->adjvex = b;
        p->weight = c;
        p->next = node[a].firstnode;
        node[a].firstnode = p;
        Node *q = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        q->adjvex = a;
        q->weight = c;
        q->next = node[b].firstnode;
        node[b].firstnode = q;
    }
    prim(k);
}
```

I don't know how to modify the both code, I try my best, thank you

Comment: Can you share the link to the problem? I would like to try my solution there first.

Comment: OK, the address is buaacoding.cn, but the language is Chinese.Also, maybe you don't have the account which can see the question. If you need, I can share my account to you privately.

Comment: Could you retranslate or explain "special number of computer which can be only connected by one line". (1) Do you mean "list or count the computers that are directly connected" or (2) do you mean "list the computers where there is only 1 routing possible" eg 3 computers that are otherwise isolated but connected via the middle computer. Or (3) do you mean "list the computer pairs where there is one critical link" eg where one cluster is connected to another cluster only through one computer or line. (1) is trivial, (3) is  interesting.

Comment: I will comment about my solution. I do not have access to the website, I can't even see the landing page. Thanks anyway

Comment: I cannot understand the meaning of K. Is it the number of special computers? Are we able to choose which computers will be the special ones?

Comment: No, the special computer number is K, that means after the K was connected by another computer, other computers cannot connect K.